# How to pass all value of ListBox Control to a function?

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I am writing a simple application to read the value a textbox and add to a listbox control . But i have to pass the listbox control to function . Any suggestion ?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    test("E:\Satyajit.txt")
End Sub

Public Function test(ByVal filename As String)
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = filename
    Dim TextLine As String
    Dim result As String = Path.GetFileName(FILE_NAME)
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
        TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
        words = TextLine.Split(New Char() {","c})
        ListBox1.Items.Add(words(3) & "," & words(4))
        objItem = ListView1.Items.Add(words(3) & "," & words(4))
    Loop
  test1(ListBox1.Items)//pass the listbox value hare
End Function

Public Function test1(ByVal value As String)
    Dim Fest As String = value
    MsgBox(Fest)
End Function
```

Comment: You want to pass all the items of the listbox? Or just 1?

Comment: The value of the selected item in the listbox?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Perhaps: 1) `Public Function test1(ByVal items As ListBox.ObjectCollection) ...`, and 2) `test1 (ListBox1.Items)`?

Comment: all the items of listbox

Comment: @Satyajit: Then simply change your "test1()" declaration per my post above.  Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the MSDN documentation.

Comment: i did the second one ..but gives error .

Comment: all the value which are added to listbox from the text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the contents of a `ListBox` to a method that is just displaying them in a `MsgBox()`.  There are two approaches you can do to accomplish what I think you're wanting.

1. You can pass `ListBox.Items` to the method and iterate through each item concatenating them into a single `String` or `StringBuilder`, then pass the String to the `MsgBox()`.  This approach makes your method dependent on ListBoxItems.
2. You can iterate through `ListBox.Items` concatenating them into a single `String` or `StringBuilder`, then pass the String to your method.  This makes your method a little more scalable.

I recommend approach #2, something like:

```
Dim MyListBox As New ListBox
MyListBox.Items.Add("Item1")
MyListBox.Items.Add("Item2")
MyListBox.Items.Add("Item3")
MyListBox.Items.Add("Item4")
MyListBox.Items.Add("Item5")

Dim sb As New StringBuilder
For Each Item In MyListBox.Items
    sb.AppendLine(Item)
Next
Test1(sb.ToString())
```

The Test1 method would look like:

```
Public Sub Test1(ByVal value As String)
    MsgBox(value)
End Sub
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the whole control to the function:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lstbox As New ListBox
    lstbox.Items.Add("Hello")
    lstbox.Items.Add("Second Item")
    lstbox.Items.Add("Third Item")

    MsgBox("The list contains: " & Length(lstbox) & " characters")
End Sub

Function Length(ByVal ctrl As ListBox) As Integer
    Dim TotalNumberOfItems As Integer = 0
    For Each item As String In ctrl.Items.ToString
        TotalNumberOfItems += 1
    Next
    Return TotalNumberOfItems
End Function
```

or just its items

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lstbox As New ListBox
    lstbox.Items.Add("Hello")
    lstbox.Items.Add("Second Item")
    lstbox.Items.Add("Third Item")

    MsgBox("The list contains: " & Length(lstbox.Items) & " characters")
End Sub

Function Length(ByVal col As ListBox.ObjectCollection) As Integer
    Dim TotalNumberOfCharacters As Integer = 0
    For Each item As String In col
        TotalNumberOfCharacters += item.Length
    Next
    Return TotalNumberOfCharacters
End Function
```

Comment: He shouldn't pass the whole control if he's only interested in the list.  It's easy to pass the list into a function: just declare the function like `test1(ByVal items As ListBox.ObjectCollection)`

Comment: show what? the listbox? or it's items? and also, show in what?

Comment: Where do you want to show them? in another listbox or in msgbox?